# Refresh GridView from ClientSide (Javascript) in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have added the Gridview control on a webPage.

I am deleting any row (one row at a time) by calling **PageMethod** as follow:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function Delete_Row(){
        PageMethods.DeleteRow(row_id, GetTimeCallback, ErrorHandler, TimeOutHandler);
      }
      GetTimeCallback = function (result) 
      {
         if (result) {
            alert('Row is deleted');
            // I want to refresh the Gridview here
          }
      }
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

where "**row_id**" is primery key of the row.

It shows the alert perfectly but does not refresh the Gridview with one less deleted row.

 what code should i write to Update the gridview? 
**NOTE:** I dont want to refresh entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write **CallBack** Function to acheive this...You can find the Callback Functionality at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210

**Edit:-**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    String cbReference =Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this,
        "arg", "ReceiveServerData", "context");
    String callbackScript;
    callbackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context)" +
        "{ " + cbReference + ";}";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
        "CallServer", callbackScript, true);

   }


 System.IO.StringWriter strDataGridHtml= new System.IO.StringWriter(); 

 public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
    {
         string idToBeDeleted=eventArgument;
         //Write deleteCode
         //DataBind the Grid
         HtmlTextWriter htwObject = new HtmlTextWriter(strDataGridHtml);
         GridViewControl.RenderControl(htwObject);
    }        

public String GetCallbackResult()
    {
        return strDataGridHtml.ToString();
    }
```

Now as you see this **strDataGridHtml** will be sent to Javascript Function ReceiveServerData...

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">

    function ReceiveServerData(rValue)
    {   
        document.getElementById("divIDWhichEncapsulategridView").innerHTML = rValue;

    }
  </script>
```

Hope this Will Help you..As i don't i have your full code i can't write the exact one...but this should give you some idea on how to proceed...And also please go through the "CallBack" Functionality in order to understand this functionality to the fullest..

Comment: Thanks Amol. It is calling serverside method "RaiseCallbackEvent" but not refresing Gridview.  I used  
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;      
        GridView1.DataSourceID = String.Empty;       
        GridView1.DataBind();      This code in that serverside method  
  But it is not working. any other ideas?

Comment: What you have to do is..After binding use HTMLTextWriter to Render the gridView control and pass it to Javascript function...In Javascript function you need to assign this text as InnerHTML to Div which Encloses GridView...

Comment: System.IO.StringWriter sWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(); HtmlTextWriter htwObject = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter); GridViewControl.RenderControl(htwObject);  this is how to render the gridview in HTMLTextWriter..then pass it to Javascript

Comment: I am totally new to this feature. will u please add this code in your ans, it will be better for me to understand...thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Amol for showing the code. But it seems not working. It deletes the row though, the HTML code it is generating does not contains the changes we made in the database and hence the DIV( with ID as "divIDWhichEncapsulategridView") shows the previous table only.