# Using Blueimp Jquery File Upload, how do I upload file to aspx.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

in Asp.net web forms.
use Blueimp Jquery File Upload.

The code that I have from their Backload example looks like this (in FileHandler.ashx.cs):

```
namespace BackloadTest
{
    public class FileHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// File handler demo for classic Asp.Net or HTML. 
        /// To access it in an Javascript ajax request use: <code>var url = "/Handler/FileHandler.ashx";</code>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// NOTE. Edit the web.config file to allow the DELETE method in the system.webServer.handlers section
        /// </remarks>
        public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                // Wrap the request into a HttpRequestBase type
                HttpRequestBase request = new HttpRequestWrapper(context.Request);


                // Create and initialize the handler
                IFileHandler handler = Backload.FileHandler.Create();
                handler.Init(request);

                // Call the execution pipeline and get the result
                IBackloadResult result = await handler.Execute();


                // Write result to the response and flush
                ResultCreator.Write(context.Response, result);
                context.Response.Flush();

            }
            catch
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to put this code in my page's aspx.cs file (instead of .ashx.cs) since on that page I have to do some extra handling after receiving the uploaded files, such as updating my data structure, refresh grid view etc.

How can I do that?

Comment: File upload with blueimps plugin uses an Ajax call to upload files, so you cannot put the server side file handler code (Backload) in a Code-Behind file. (aspx.cs). As I understand you, you need to update the client side ui. In this case you usually grab the results returned from Backload and update the ui with client side JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. I have two questions. 

First, you said blueimps plugin uses an Ajax call to upload files, but Ajax call can be sent to a Webmethod in aspx.cs, right? 

Second, if I can only use ashx, then for me to update an object/refresh grid view of aspx.cs, I have to make another ajax call to a Webmethod in aspx.cs after I get result back from Backload?

Comment: First of all, Backload can be in a page event handler or page/webmethod or an ashx handler. The problem you are facing is that the client side plugin is developed for using Ajax calls. You might try to prevent the plugin from making ajax calls (disable upload button) and finally make a full page request with you own button. Or you use the ashx handler or a webmethod and process the result in Javascript. Another way to update your server controls is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215384/refresh-gridview-from-clientside-javascript-in-asp-net